# How to get MacBook Air to automatically connect to company guest network?

Tags: wifi, network, macbook-pro

My company has a guest wifi network for use by non-company issued machines. Since getting my MacBook Air recently, I've wanted to bring it in and use it around the office.

I can easily connect to the (unsecured) guest wifi network but then the first time I try to access a website I get a login page where I need to use my company userid/password to gain access. This is kind of like it works in a hotel.

This works fine except if I put my machine to sleep and wake it up again, I need to re-login again. This re-login happens all day long. Very annoying. I'm wondering if I can configure my Mac to automatically login for me. Is there a way of configuring the wireless networking on my Mac to automatically pass my userid/password for when upon connecting?

Comment: I think [Fluid.app](http://fluidapp.com/) might have a chance at working here, but I'm having trouble finding the best way to test it to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - not sure I am getting how Fluid would help though.

Answer (score 1):

If the login functions through a Webpage, it's probable that the closest you could come is to write a script to fill in the form for you.

If you're lucky, the login form might use a [HTML GET request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Request_methods) so you could to bookmark the page that logs you in. Pay attention to what redirects occur once you login. If you see something like this:
`http://example.com?name=fred&pword=qwerty`, you can bookmark that and go to it to log in automatically.

This is unlikely, though, because it isn't a very secure choice for your company. The form probably uses a [POST request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29).

Comment: Yeah I can see the url quite plainly. I guess I was wondering whether there is a formal protocol for logging into a system like this. But the other thing you made me think of is I could write a Safari extension to do the automatic login. However, if the first thing I want to do is run my mail client or anything non-browser based it will simply fail until I go to Safari and do this login. Which is annoying.

Comment: @Marplesoft If you see the URL that logs you in, you can bookmark it. Just open that page to log in. However, if you see a normal URL (without the ?name=fred&pword=qwerty), you'll have to type it in manually.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. But yeah I think it's a form POST, not just URL query string that passes the userid/password.

Comment: @Marplesoft If it's a post request, I don't believe you can automate it.

Comment: You actually can, it's quite simple really: http://superuser.com/questions/149329/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-curl

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do a POST request using curl from terminal. You need to figure out the key/values pairs that are being passed, and the action url, and then submit to that url.